# How to get the result of a background job?

Tags: return-value, jobs, job-scheduling, dolphindb

My background job returns a table. How do I view this table?

For example:

```
def func1(x){
    t = table(take(1..1000,x) as Id,rand(100.00,x) as qyt)
    return t
}
submitJob("getTable","getTable",func1,10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `getJobReturn(job_id)` to check the result of a batch job. *job_id* is the ID of the job. In your example, you could use the following script:

```
result = getJobReturn("getTable")
```